# Construct Parent class from the Child class [PHP/OOP]

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I would like to do instantiate a class A and then instantiate a class B (that extends A) from the reference of Class A.

In other words, I have this classes:

```
class A{
    protected $name;

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function setName($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected $value;

    public function __construct($value){
        $this->value=$value;
    }

    public function getValue(){
        return $this->value;
    }
    public function setValue($value){
        $this->value=$value;
    }
}
```

And I would like to do something like :

```
$a = new ('Name in A class');
$b = new ($a, 'Value in B class');
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

To construct the parent class from its child you can call the parent's constructor by using a **parent** keyword.

```
class B extends A{
    function __construct($name, $value){
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->value=$value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this method but if I do it this way the object B "doesn't know' that an object A were instantiated before. I want that my constructor in the B class constructs the B class FROM the instantiated A class.